# Merging 2 data frame with different sizes in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I want to merge two data frame with  different size (139161 and 5024) with this order

```
data<-merge(canal,growth,by="animal", all=T)
```

but the new `dim(data)` is 144185 which have to be `139161`.

Comment: This could be because some observations in the smaller data set could not be matched in the bigger one.. So they were just appended.

Comment: 1- `growth$animal` has to contain only unique values for this to work. 2- add `, all.x = TRUE` to your merge instead of `all = TRUE`